# How to pass argument to npm debug config in Intellij

Tags: npm, intellij-idea

I am trying to run a graphql app locally, it has the following line in the script section in the package.json:

```
"component": "NODE_ENV=development NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 GRPC_VERBOSITY=debug GRPC_TRACE=all DEBUG=* npx --node-arg=--inspect graphql-server ./components/$TYPE/$NAME/lib/manifest.json --component=$NAME"
```

The normal way to start the app is to run `TYPE=domain NAME=reservations npm run component`, and running that from the terminal works.

I am however having some issues and need to run the the app in debug mode to find out what exactly is happening with one of the requests.

I added the command to the debug config [image: debug config]

I tried to add the `TYPE=domain NAME=reservations` in the environment, and in the variables, but in both cases it didn't work: instead of getting the `./components/components/reservations/lib/manifest.json`
it tries to find `./components/lib/manifest.json`

I tried other options without success, hardcoding the path isn't an option, it doesn't work, I need to pass the $TYPE and the $NAME just like in that command  `TYPE=domain NAME=reservations npm run component`.

Do you know the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Variables have to be added to the **Environment:** field, like

[image]